# How to write this generic object program?

Tags: java, arrays, comparator, rectangles, generic-programming

Problem: Define a Rectangle class that provides getLength and getWidth methods. Using the
findMax routines in Figure 1.18, write a main that creates an array of Rectangle
and finds the largest Rectangle first on the basis of area, and then on the basis of perimeter.

What I did so far was create a class rectangle with parameters width and height in the constructor. After that I implemented the two getter methods in which the instance variable width and height are return for their respective getter methods. So I need help with the second part.

Figure 1.18

```
1 // Generic findMax, with a function object.
2 // Precondition: a.size( ) > 0.
3 public static <AnyType>
4 AnyType findMax( AnyType [ ] arr, Comparator<? super AnyType> cmp )
5 {
6 int maxIndex = 0;
7
8 for( int i = 1; i < arr.size( ); i++ )
9 if( cmp.compare( arr[ i ], arr[ maxIndex ] ) > 0 )
10 maxIndex = i;
11
12 return arr[ maxIndex ];
13 }
14
15 class CaseInsensitiveCompare implements Comparator<String>
16 {
17 public int compare( String lhs, String rhs )
18 { return lhs.compareToIgnoreCase( rhs ); }
19 }
20
21 class TestProgram
22 {
23 public static void main( String [ ] args )
24 {
25 String [ ] arr = { "ZEBRA", "alligator", "crocodile" };
26 System.out.println( findMax( arr, new CaseInsensitiveCompare( ) ) )
27 }
28 }
```

Comment: Basically just struggling with the implementation of using the findMax routine and the comparator. I also created a bunch of random rectangle objects via an array as required by the problem

Comment: you have a `findMax` routine. All you need to do is define your `Comparator<Rectangle>`s and you can plug in.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

- You can't use .size(), that only exists for Collection objects, not primitive arrays - use .length instead.
- Generally use E or T for types, E for element.
- Please use braces to keep code readable

Example

```
public static <E> E findMax(E[] arr, Comparator<? super E> cmp) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (cmp.compare(arr[i], arr[maxIndex]) > 0) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return arr[maxIndex];
}
```

We need a comparator to compare by area.

```
private static class AreaComparator implements Comparator<Rectangle> {
    public int compare(Rectangle lhs, Rectangle rhs) {
        return Double.compare(lhs.getArea(), rhs.getArea());
        // <== delegate to Double.compare() for nice readable solution
    }
}
```

And a Rectangle class, which I assume you have already? Here it defines getArea().

```
private static class Rectangle {
    private double width;
    private double height;
    public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
        super();
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangle [width=" + width + ", height=" + height + "]";
    }
}
```

Test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(findMax(new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(1, 2), new Rectangle(3, 4) }, new AreaComparator()));
    System.out.println(findMax(new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(4, 5), new Rectangle(3, 4) }, new AreaComparator()));
}
```